# Is markdown for reference-style links not working?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, hyperlinks, markdown

I am using the syntax for reference-style links as shown here:
[Markdown Editing Help - WordPress Development Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/166699/33393)

From the example:

> Here's a reference-style link to `[Google][1]`. `[1]:`
>   http://www.google.com/

Testing the example in this post:
Here's a reference-style link to [Google](http://www.google.com/).
Also, line breaks are stripped here^. Isn't it supposed to display a small 1 next to "Google" and display the reference url at the bottom of the post?

Answer (score 3):

Your link is perfectly functional. :)

"Reference" style is only internal markdown syntax, it still produces common inline link, not "references" as in broken out to the bottom of the document (which it might mean in other systems).

Comment: Oh ok, as long as the links still point to the right place. I only started using it after seeing a post that had them and it had a little index at the bottom kind if like a wiki does